# Is it posible to generate ios app from working android app with cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

My question is if i can get the ios version of a working android app using Cordova? I have tried adding a platform like this:

```
//I add the platform
cordova platform add ios
//I compile the project
cordova build ios
```

Then i try to run it but it works badly, it loads a blank screen, the project says its running. I think its a configuration problem. The automatically created config.xml(ios) looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.project.appios" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="false" />
    <preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="false" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="HandleOpenUrl">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVHandleOpenURL" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="IntentAndNavigationFilter">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="GestureHandler">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGestureHandler" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="false" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
</widget>
```

The root config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.medife.appios" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>*****</name>
    <description>
        ******************
    </description>
    <author email="*******************************">
        *********
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/default-568-iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/default-667-iphone.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/default-736-iphone.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    </platform>
    <icon src="res/logo/logo.png" />
</widget>
```

I have removed author, description and email...

UPDATE: I have noticed, in XCode console, that some plugins are missing, so im checking other stackoverflow answers about this issue. I think is due to that the backend of the app was made with an older version of iOS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be you only need to do `Cordova Prepare` while configure with ios.

Comment: @Edu, which version of iOS are you using? Any error trace? Are you making ajax calls in your app to render page?

Comment: @Gandhi im using latest version of iOS, at least i updated it to the latest. I have no error trace, but it is more difficult to lookup jquery errors as i cant use google developer tools in iOS. Im making Ajax calls but not in render. Also i have mentioned it but it is working really fine on Android. Something that i havent mentioned but maybe helps is that i dont have a splashscreen set yet.

Comment: @Edu, you can use the debug in Web Inspector under Safari's Develop menu to debug the issue in iOS to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Gandhi i will give it a try, but i dont think its a jquery issue as it works fine on Android, im almost sure its a Config.xml problem. But i will try it.

EDIT: i have tried it, blank console, no error, not initiation, not console logs, nothing, so it is not initiating jquery...very odd...

Comment: @Edu if it jquery initiation problem you wil definitely get console error in web inspector while reloading the application. Please give it a try

Comment: @jcesarmobile what part of it? Isn't the config.xml the important part? I mean, the rest is generated automatically and already works on android quite well

Comment: maybe if you provide the root config.xml and not the generated config.xml. Providing the cordova-ios platform that was added might be helpful too

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have edited my original post and pasted the root config.xml, but i dont understand what do you mean by cordova ios-platfom ? You mean version? If that is the case im using latest: 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it. Im posting the answer so if someone comes across the same problem it can help:

First a few things:
1) There is no problem with splash screen plugin, it works really good, i just updated it and it was beautiful.
2) I had to change some jquery as it does not run fine on ios:
I changed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    onDeviceReady();
});
```

With

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

And lastly, this is my config.xml (working on both Android and iOS):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.medife.mobile" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>APP NAME</name>
    <description>
        YOUR DESCRIPTION
    </description>
    <author email="YOURMAIL" href="">
        YOUR NAME
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="7500" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    </platform>
    <icon src="res/logo/logo.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.3.0" />
</widget>
```

My punctual problem was that i was using `window.outerHeight` and `window.outerWidth` to get height and width and it didnt work on ios, i had to use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` instead.